# Concatenating Inside an Excel Shape

Tags: excel, concatenation

Is it possible to use a `Concatenate` formula (or using &) inside an Excel shape?

So I understand you can link a cell inside an Excel shape (e.g. =A1) but is it possible to write ="Total YTD "&A1 (if A1 is a total #) or `=CONCATENATE("Total YTD ",A1)`

When I try to do this, it gives me the error "This formula is missing a range reference or a defined name"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing the formula work in one cell and then referencing the cell?

It is indirect, but it overcomes the apparent limitation of the shape object. It will also let you use special characters like &Char(13) to generate carriage returns in the text box as well.

An alternate means may be to copy a cell containing the formula and pasting it as a linked picture. With this it will allow you to effect the object with conditional formatting.